# Can I optimize segmented Sieve of Eratosthenes

Tags: c++, counter

I am trying to find the number of primes in a given range in c++. But it still shows TLE. Can I optimize it further?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main() 
{
int T;
std::cin>>T;
while(T--){
    int r,Y;
    cin >> r>>Y;                                  
    int count=0;
    int l=1;
    vector<bool>isPrime(r - l + 1,true); //filled by true
    for (long long i = 2; i * i <= r; ++i) {
        for (long long j = max(i * i, (l + (i - 1)) / i  * i); j <= r; j += i) {
           if(isPrime[j - l]){ 
              isPrime[j - l] = false;
              count++;
        }
    }
} 

count=isPrime.size()-count-1;
std::cout<<count<<"\n";
}  
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could stop including the entire C++ standard library  just to get vector and iostream. Probably decrease the build time by close to an order of magnitude.

Comment: `vector<bool>` stores packed bits but because it's packed, it's a bit slower than a `vector` of a regular type. If you need speed more than space consider using something else like `int8_t` or if you wanna get really wasteful `int_fast8_t`.

Comment: If you can get away with it, build the sieve once, not every iteration.

Comment: start using meaningfull names. The only ones are main and IsPrime. I got tired of decoding your text ,I've got better things to do.

Comment: Here's an idea: You only need to calculate the prime number list once. To find the number of primes in between two numbers L and R, you could perform two binary searches on that prime number list for a `O(logN)` query time (assuming that you calculate the primes in sorted order).